# where is the linked library located for ios project

Tags: ios

I am new to ios development. I know that for ios project in build phases,there maybe linked with .framework file, .a file and .dylib, I know that .framework file is located in iphone file system, so where is .a file and .dylib file located after project built and run? Are they  built in the bundle resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framework files are in a private location, you might have to jail break to find out. Most likely it's the same as OS X, which is `/System/Library/Frameworks`. Third party frameworks cannot be used on iOS, it's technically possible but banned under the app store rules.

.a and .dylib files are embedded in the application binary at compile time, just like everything else. iOS apps are deployed as a "*.ipa" file and everything is inside that file, there are no separate files except for user data.

Comment: Ah, .dylib files (dynamic libraries) are loaded by the iOS and shared by all apps that need them.  They are not part of the app itself.